# How to start graph with 25 and end with 24

Tags: graph, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to start graph date [image]wise which starts from 25th of previous month to 24th of this month

I have tried format option to start from 25 but not able to end with 24

Need a graph like this. And how to get the day names(mon,tue,...)

Comment: do you have a calendar dimenson? or other table that drive the dates?

Comment: No i do not have any calendar dimensions.I just have a column in the table which contains date

Comment: Can you update the question why the dates should start and end on those dates, is that your reporting period

Comment: yes that is my reporting period every month

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions, first how to sort in a specific order. You will need to add a calendar dimension that joins on the dates. This table will extend the logic required for the sorting. In the below example you have the dates, with a sort order, which I'm going to assume is your reporting dates. You can then use the sort by column, to sort the date in another order.

[image: Sort by column]

In the below example, the date can now be sorted by the numerical order, and the sorting applied in the chart A-Z of Z-A formatting options

[image]

Two get the Day values you will need to create a calculated column that changes the format of the date

`Column = FORMAT([YourDateColumn], "dddd")`

For example `01/01/2019` will give you Friday